# React property destructuring in the constructor. Is a good idea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Normally i do the object destructuring for the props inside the render method.

like:

```
render() {
const { props1, props2, props3 } = this.props;
...other code
```

Is very boring because if i need to define a method in my object and maybe i need the props here, i need to destructuring again my props inside the function.

for example:

```
func = () => {
  const { props1, props2, props3 } = this.props;
}
```

There is a way to do this one time for a component? Maybe in the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do destructuring only one time, the way I think is the best is using functional components and hooks like the example bellow

```
export default function Banans(props) {

    const {
        name,
        type,
        color
    } = props

    const bananaColor = () => {
        // here you can access the props without destructuring again
        console.log(color)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {name}
            <button onClick={() => bananaColor()}>Banana color</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In the constructor you can set states from the props. But, if the parent change the props, you need to change the states or not. Look this lifecycle method: [UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops).

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
             props1 = props.props1,
             props2 = props.props2,
             props3 = props.props3
        };
          }

        func = () => {
          let sum = this.state.props1 + 1;
          code...
        }

          render() {
            return (
              <div>
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                <h2>It is {this.state.props1}.</h2>
                <h2>It is {this.state.props2}.</h2>
                <h2>It is {this.state.props3}.</h2>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of class components, you can destructure the props only one time in the e.g. in the constructor and save them as class properties but the problem you will face is whenever the component is re-rerendered, and lets say the props that are passed by the parent component are updated, the initial destructured prop values saved as class properties will be used by the render method that will be old and outdated. So updating the view wont work in this case.

The main advantage of desctructuring is to make syntax short and avoid long expressions e.g. not repeating `this.props` again and again. If you want both 
destructuring(short syntax)+updated props(updated view) the right approach is to destructure them everytime  in the render method(so that you can use them directly without saving as class members).

You can also use `componentWillUpdate` or `componentWillReceiveProps` hooks and save props as class properties and update them everytime but again you would need `this` to access that prop inside `render` method. Saving them inside state will not be a good idea here because you will need destructuring `this.state` again for a cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If the component is functional, you could something like

`const myComponent = (props) => {
      const {props1, props2} = props;
      return(
           <div>
             <li>{props1}</li>
             <li>{props2}</li>
           </div>
)}`